# Alias ActionResult return a Different View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

I have two ActionResults in my controller:

```
public ActionResult CustomerEdit(int recid) {
    ....
    return View(c);
}
```

and

```
public ActionResult CustomerNew()
{
    ....
    return View(c);
}
```

I have no need whatsoever to recreate a CustomerNew view because it will be just a copy of the CustomerEdit view.

How do I make the CustomerNew controller return the CustomerEdit view to the browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return CustomerEdit view to the browser from the CustomerNew action result

`public ActionResult CustomerNew()
{
    ....
    return View("CustomerEdit",c);
}`

If it doesn't work try

`public ActionResult CustomerNew()
{
    ....
    return View("~/Views/.../CustomerEdit.cshtml",c) // CustomerEdit.cshtml path
}`

Comment: So the "c" in View(c) is an object that has to be passed to the view.  So should I use " View("CustonerEdit", c); " ?

Comment: so it will be View("CustomerEdit",c)